# Duvida ao Ligar formulário no PHP para enviar por email

Tags: php, email

Eu estou com um pequeno problema na hora de ligar o formulário de contato para ser enviado por email, ele não esta enviando por email e eu não consegui entender o motivo disso, segue abaixo o código em html com o nome contato.html

```html
 <form action="sendemail.php" id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post"  >
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="Nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
                       <p class="help-block">Obrigatorio</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
                      <p class="help-block">Obrigatorio</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="Instituição" class="form-control" placeholder="Instituição" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Escreve sua menssagem" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Abaixo está o codigo php com o nome sendemail.php

```html
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['Nome'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['Instituicao'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to     = 'meuemail@hotmail.com';//replace with your email




$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Eu sou bem noob no php por hora, por isso estou com esse problema,
o site já está no servidor e eu não estou conseguindo achar o erro.

Comment: OI Gabriel, onde está hospedada a sua aplicação? Dependente de onde for, você deve usar alguns parâmetros adicionais na função mail.

Answer (score 0):

**Gabriel**, corrija o nome do campo `Instituição` para `Instituicao` (sem acentos).

A função `mail()` do PHP não é mais recomendada para envio de emails uma vez que diversos motivos impedem o email de chegar ao destinatário, até mesmo um simples bloqueio do servidor onde o site está hospedado ou mesmo as verificações de SPAM do destinatário.

Envie utilizando servidor SMTP e uma classe apropriada para isto.

Recomendo o `phpmailer`, é famoso e muito simples de implementar veja um tutorial simples:

http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Enviar_e-mails_pelo_PHP_usando_o_PHPMailer

Comment: Outro link sobre o assunto: http://blog.patriciodossantos.net/2012/05/enviando-e-mail-com-o-phpmailer/

Comment: Não funcionou, eu segui corretamente o tutorial e não funciona do mesmo jeito. Além de que esse phpmailer serve para eu enviar email para diversas pessoas, eu gostaria apenas de enviar pra min a parte do formulario para eu saber a pessoa que entrou em contato.

Comment: @GabrielSilva, você checou as configurações SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

Como citado acima também lhe recomendo usar a classe de envio de email **PHPMailler**. Eu a utilizo já tem um bom tempo e nunca tive problemas com a mesma,
é simples de usar e se seu e-mail estiver no padrão não entrará como spam nas caixas de entradas dos servidores de e-mails (Gmail, Hotmail, etc), por que a mesma tem todo um processo de autenticação.

Dica: Não use nomenclatura de variáveis ou vetores com caracteres especiais, você terá problemas com a codificação do arquivo futuramente.

http://www.revistaphp.com.br/artigo.php?id=78